# Explain this code that calculates working days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, formula

I'm hoping someone can help explain how this piece of code works?

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Person.FullName, dbo.Person.Initials,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @startdate, @enddate) + 1) -
       (DATEDIFF(wk, @startdate, @enddate) * 2) -
       (CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @startdate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
       (CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @enddate) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
       (Select Count(*) FROM  [dbo].[W2BankHoliday] 
        Where [dbo].[W2BankHoliday].[bhDate] >= @StartDate AND [dbo].[W2BankHoliday].bhDate < @EndDate) AS WorkDays
FROM dbo.Person
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: What does the +1 and *2 do? Why count(*) from a table that holds bank holiday dates?

Comment: What is this code trying to solve for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a breakdown of each part of that query

```
SELECT 

    /* persons details */
    dbo.Person.FullName, dbo.Person.Initials,

    /* difference in days from start to end */
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @startdate, @enddate) + 1) - 


    /* difference in weeks times two (to allocate for weekends) */
    (DATEDIFF(wk, @startdate, @enddate) * 2) -

    /* discounting if started or finished on a weekend */
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @startdate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @enddate) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -

    /* discounting all bank holidays */
    (
        Select Count(*) FROM  [dbo].[W2BankHoliday] 
        Where [dbo].[W2BankHoliday].[bhDate] >= @StartDate 
        AND [dbo].[W2BankHoliday].bhDate < @EndDate
    ) AS WorkDays
FROM dbo.Person
```

Now that this actually means is

```
difference in days from start to end

minus

difference in weeks times two (to allocate for weekends)

minus

discounting if started or finished on a weekend

minus 

discounting all bank holidays
```

Well, a little better explanation would be

```
Total days between beginning to end

minus

number of days for weekends

minus

number of days to be taken off if started or finished on weekend

minus 

number of bank holidays between start and finish date
```

I presume you are not getting the correct answer.  This may be because you are doing Start-end in the very first line, whereas you should be doing end-start.

Comment: What does the +1 and 2 do? Why count() from a table that holds bank holiday dates?